# Error while updating to Meteor 1.4

Tags: node.js, meteor

Recently, Meteor has been upgraded to v1.4, well that's great! Unfortunately for me, I cannot upgrade it and have an error log like this.

```
While loading package npm-bcrypt@0.8.7:
error: Command failed:
/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.1oo55z5++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm
rebuild --no-bin-links --update-binary
sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv
"/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.1oo55z5++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.1oo55z5++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
/root/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.8.7.1i1986o++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-1fwxhnx/npm-debug.log
sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv
"/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.1oo55z5++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0.1oo55z5++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"rebuild" "--no-bin-links" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!
/root/.meteor/packages/npm-bcrypt/.0.8.7.1i1986o++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/.temp-1fwxhnx/npm-debug.log
```

I already tried to uninstall and install node js and npm, I thought it will success but the same error still showed up. Can anyone help me?? thank you

Comment: it seems to be using node 4.4.7. meteor uses 0.10. not sure if that is the problem. did you manually change the node version in the .meteor files?

Comment: no i dont change manually, i change globally using nvm to change the version. Well how to change node version in meteor files?? I just install it and it automaticaly using version 0.10

Comment: It is in.meteor/local/build/.node_version.txt. I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Looks like Meteor 1.4 uses Node 4.4.7 by default.

Comment: You need to add this package `meteor add npm-bcrypt` If the problem persists update nodejs and npm and also your packages

Answer (score 0):

A few different solutions for your issue, depending on platform at:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7469#issuecomment-235563857

(Meteor problems are usually easier solved through github issues than Stack Overflow Questions)